# How to test a large sample if it is normaly distributed?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, normal-distribution

I am dealing with normaly testing of large samples. As stated here:

[Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless/)

Normally testing is essentially useless, if the sample is too large. Even visual testing cannot give a clear statement about the distribution?

So, how to test a large sample if the distribution is normal distributed?

Comment: What is the purpose of your normality testing?

Comment: My purpose is, to test if the distribution is normaly distributed or not?

Comment: Why do you want to know? What will you do if it is normal? What will you do if it is not normal? Is this a testing of residuals from a regression?

Comment: Yes it is testing of residuals from a regression. However, I am interested how huge data sets are testen for normal distribution, and if its possible to get a meaningful result?

Comment: See the points made [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36212/what-tests-do-i-use-to-confirm-that-residuals-are-normally-distributed/36220#36220)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing residuals is the classic case where formal normality testing goes astray, see the first answer in the question you linked to. This isn't unique to normality testing, it's a problem with p-values for *any* very large data set - that is, results can be statistically highly significant but of no practical import.

But I think this may be an exact duplicate question, unless you can give some reason why it is different than the question you linked to.

Comment: Ok so generally said, it depends on your goal how valid your answer about the normal distribution is?

Comment: It depends on the consequences of the amount of non-normality for the technique that you wish to use.