# Is there a good specification error test against a generalized alternative?

Tags: model-selection

Suppose I believe a sample is drawn from a population that is distributed according to some specified distributional family. I intend to estimate the parameters of the distribution using some appropriate method.  However, somewhere along the way I may come to suspect that my original assumptions with respect to the functional form of the distribution may be incorrect.

If my original assumption was that the distribution was normal, I knowa number of the tests for normality that I could use. But suppose I think my data has some distribution other than the normal. Are there any good tests that can be used for an arbitrary distribution against a generalized alternative (perhaps subject to some regularity conditions for it to be reliable)?

For example, if I think my distribution is gamma or log-normal, are there any well-understood tests, with a literature I could find describing when they work, that would reject those choices if the data were clearly bi-modal, or strongly fat-tailed or thin-tailed relative to what is expected given a range of parameter values that is broadly consistent with the data?

(I am looking forward to reaching the point where I con suggest tags. In this case, I was surprised that there is no "specification error" tag.)

Comment: "*a number of the tests for normality that I could use*" - off the top of my head I can only think of one suitable "off the shelf" test (perhaps arguably a second), though I can think of a bunch that would work if you specified, rather than estimated, the parameters. Which ones were you thinking of?

Comment: @Glen_b: I was thinking of Shapiro-Wilk and the K-squared test, but I know there are others in common use.

Comment: Yes, the Shapiro-Wilk would make sense. I'm not sure what the other one is. Sometimes tests get called different names - which test is the "K-squared"? Do you have a link or reference or an example? Did you mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Agostino%27s_K-squared_test) one, that's related to the Bowman-Shenton/Jarque-Bera? If so, that would not satisfy all your requirements (though I think it's generally a good test). Specifically it can be blind to some bimodal alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any good tests that can be used for an arbitrary distribution against a generalized alternative (perhaps subject to some regularity conditions for it to be reliable)?

There are - but not when you have to estimate parameters.

For many distributions you could do something akin to a Shapiro-Francia test, but the distribution of critical values would be different for each distribution.

You could also do something like a Lilliefors test ... and again, critical values would be different for each distribution.

> For example, if I think my distribution is gamma or log-normal, are there any well-understood tests, with a literature I could find describing when they work, that would reject those choices if the data were clearly bi-modal, or strongly fat-tailed or thin-tailed relative to what is expected given a range of parameter values that is broadly consistent with the data?

In the case of the lognormal, take logs and test for normality using a test suitable for testing normality with estimated parameters, such as the Shapiro-Wilk.

In the case of a gamma, you could:

- perform a Lilliefors-type test (a Kolmogorov-Smirnov-type test where parameters are estimated, but the distribution is simulated to take account of the effect of the esitmation)
- do the same type of thing with an Anderson-Darling test (this tends to be much less affected by parameter estimation - see the discussion in D'Agostino & Stephens *Goodness of fit Techniques*.
- test the correlation in a gamma probability plot (that's what I mean by a test akin to the Shapiro-Francia). For example, for an approximate test, one could perform a Wilson-Hilferty type approach (i.e. a cube root transformation) and test normality, though there are other approaches for "gamma-probability" type plots.

There's also a smooth test for the gamma that should be very suitable:

De Boeck, B., O. Thas, J. C.W. Rayner & D. J. Best, (2011)
*Smooth tests for the gamma distribution*
Journal of Statistical Computation and Simulation
Volume 81, Issue 7, p843-855

Since many people haven't heard of these, I'll give a quick outline of them: Smooth tests consist basically of parameterizing the log-density of the data as the hypothesized log-density plus a set of orthonormal functions (that is, orthogonal to the null as well as each other); the functions differ for each density tested. There are some packages that do smooth tests in R, but I don't know that the gamma one is in there at the moment. They do deal with parameter estimation in a very simple way and generally have good power properties.

R packages that do smooth tests include [ddst](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ddst/index.html) and [smoothtest](http://biomath.ugent.be/~othas/smooth2/R-Package.html).

--

edit to respond to questions in comments:

> where I could hand my data and my preferred distribution to a package and say"Is this a *_*_ distribution?" and get back some result that would let me answer this question in a straightforward way

You really can't get a "*Is this a *_*_ distribution?*" test. Imagine for a second that there was something like a K-S test but where you could estimate parameters (i.e. a truly omnibus test). Even so, in general for a given sample there would be an infinite number of distributions which would not be rejected by such a test. Statistical tests can help you rule out things ('that's clearly not exponential!') but not to say "that must be Weibull" or something like that, in the same way that you can say "the data are plainly inconsistent with a population mean of 100" but not to say "well, the population mean must be 157.32". Failure to reject a null doesn't tell you the null is true.

> Instead, I would need to construct an analogue to one of the normality tests, and then compute my own critical values by Monte Carlo methods or something. Is that right?

Pretty much.

Well, there's the chi-square tests, I suppose.

However, I think you'd probably be best served by pursuing the Anderson-Darling test, but adjusting for parameter estimation.

I think potentially it comes at least fairly close to doing what you want (again, see D'Agostino and Stephens' book on that). In particular, it may be that fairly simple kinds of adjustment to critical values to deal with parameter estimation may be possible in that case.

Comment: So it sounds like there is not a fill-in-the-blank test, where I could hand my data and my preferred distribution to a package and say"Is this a ____ distribution?" and get back some result that would let me answer this question in a straightforward way. (This is what I was hoping for). Instead, I would need to construct an analogue to one of the normality tests, and then compute my own critical values by Monte Carlo methods or something. Is that right?

Comment: see edit to my answer

Comment: Let me tell you what I am really trying to do in case that affects how you are reading my question. I am actually trying to supply my own answer through numerical experiments to another question of mine: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58080/approximating-a-compound-distribution-with-a-mixture-required-n

Comment: Let me tell you what I'm really trying to do in case that affects your answer. I am actually trying to do numerical experiments to answer another question of mine: [Approximating compound distribution with mixture](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58080/approximating-a-compound-distribution-with-a-mixture-required-n) about approximating a compound distribution with a finite mixture. I thought I would produce some finite mixtures of my generating distribution (generalized gamma) to see if the can be distinguished from the compound distribution (Dagum) by some standard test.

Comment: Context helps. Pretty much any reasonable test people use will distinguish if you take a large enough sample size. It doesn't sound like you're answering a question you don't already know the answer to. Why would a hypothesis test be a meaningful way to investigate the quality of the approximation?  [See also](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless) and then [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36212/what-tests-do-i-use-to-confirm-that-residuals-are-normally-distributed/36220#36220)

Comment: The links you provide offer persuasive arguments that hypothesis testing is the wrong way to decide whether a discrete mixture is likely to be a good approximation of a compound distribution. I am persuaded. So what is the right way? Is there a good way?

Comment: Sure; you could either measure the discrepancy between the two in some meaningful way ("how different are they?"; this *might* in some circumstances use one of the measures of discrepancy that goodness of fit tests are based on - in essence, an 'effect size') or you could measure the *impact* of the discrepancy on whatever you want to use the approximation for ("how much difference does it make?").

Comment: I apologize if I am being obtuse, but I am feeling stuck & unsure how to proceed. If I generate the data myself, I can of course measure the difference between the approximation and the true distribution. But I had hoped to derive some rule of thumb that could be extended to situations with real data, where I don't know the functional form with certainty, or the true population parameter values for the whole population or for the sub-population distributions I am mixing.  I don't see how to achieve confidence in my mixture approximation in this more realistic setting.

Comment: The problem is I'm also not in a position to be a great deal more specific, not knowing what your precise needs are. I could write 30 pages of possibilities and still not talk about whatever it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This and a.half-dozen of my other recent questions at all motivated by my desire to do parametric estimates of income distribution for, e.g., the USA & its states, or a state and its counties. Whuber and others have suggested that it is impossible to do this consistantly. In response, I am hypothesizing that if the national distributing is composite, a finite mixture of state distributions may approximate it well, under certain restrictions.

Comment: But what would constitute a good fit for you? Failing that, what things would you seek to find out from such a mixture?

Comment: In this context, I would call a compound distribution good-fitting if: (1) for at least one of the standard criteria of fit (mean squared error, MAP, etc.) I don't know of another distribution with (2) the same or fewer parameters that (3) better fits the sample data by that criteria.  I would call the mixture a good fit if it fit the merged data set better or only trivially worse than the compound distribution estimated directly. But the purpose here is to choose a distribution for a program of research, so it would be good to know this quality isn't an accident of one data set.

Comment: Notice that in defining 'good' you say 'trivially worse' without defining 'worse'? This is kind of the problem; you just defined good as 'not bad'. I'm trying to get at *precisely how the approximation matters for your application*, what's it sensitive to, which features of the distribution impact whatever you're using it for?

Comment: I'm hoping to do a multi-country, multi-level exploration of the causes and consequences of income inequality.  I'm not testing a single hypothesis; I'm planing a program of research. For some I have good micro data; other only official summaries. I am concerned that I may be estimating income distribution inlower-level aggregations in a way fundimentally inconsistant with the higher level groupings; & I'm looking for some approach to harmonize the estimates. This notion of finite mixtures strucke me as a possable approach to so doing.

Comment: At any rate, I'v upticked you answer, as amended. It both answered my original question, and (more usefully if more frustratingly) persuaded me that it was not the question I wanted to ask.

Comment: Interesting additional information; at least I have a little more sense of what you need it to be able to do.