# How to test whether it is valid causal inference

Tags: regression, causality

definition of average causal effect
$$ ACE = E(C_1) - E(C_0) $$
$$ ACE = E(Y|X=1) - E(Y|X=0) $$
given the condition that
$$ X \bot (Y(0), Y(1)) $$

So if I have a regression

```
m <- lm(y~x)
```

whose residual is perfectly normally distributed:
[image]

Can I assert that coefficient of $X$ is the average causal effect of $X \rightarrow Y$ ?

If so, how can I test whether that $m\$redisuals$ is normally distributed along $X$?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that, given your experimental design, you can justify the statements about independence of assignment of treatment from treatment outcome, you can assert the coefficient of X to be the average causal effect of X on Y.

If you mean that you can't necessarily assert the independence of assignment of treatment from treatment outcome, you cannot identify the coefficient of X as the causal effect.

The question of normality of residuals is covered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36212/what-tests-do-i-use-to-confirm-that-residuals-are-normally-distributed)

`