# Is the Anderson-Darling test or Shapiro-Wilk test more powerful?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normality-assumption

In the testing of normality, how would the 2 compare? Is one significantly better than the other?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36212/what-tests-do-i-use-to-test-if-error-residuals-are-normally-distributed

Comment: There was a recent question on the SPSS Nabble group that gave a reference to [a similar question](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/jarque-bera-test-td5714665.html#a5714669). Also some googling for Shapiro Wilks power finds a question [here that is highly rated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1645/1036). Possible duplicate without further clarification.

Comment: Which is more powerful depends on which alternatives you consider - since they measure nonnormality differently, each has good power against slightly different things. As general tests of normality, both are excellent - with really good power against a wide range of alternatives. Neither is uniformly better. Do you need power studies?

Comment: @Taylor The question you linked is relevant here, but this is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: Glen_b is right. The recent similar question asked how to test model residuals for normality. One respondent cited a paper that shows Shapiro-Wilk is more powerful than Anderson-Darling. But he does not cite what the assumptions are that lead to the result. I mentioned that it cannot be globally true. You might want to look at the similar questions. As mbq points out, the recent one which I am referring to is definitely not an exact duplicate. Andy W. gives in his second link a question that is very close and has the answers you are looking for but does not address power.

Comment: An answer on the recent (preceding one) does provide a reference that does.